# Reachable vertices from each other

Tags: graph

Given a directed graph, I need to find all vertices v, such that, if u is reachable from v, then v is also reachable from u. I know that, the vertex can be find using BFS or DFS, but it seems to be inefficient. I was wondering whether there is a better solution for this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: look up algorithms for strongly connected components. any algorithm you apply will be built upon some kind of search along edges, bfs/dfs just being systematic flavors. unless you have special a priori information about connectedness structure of the graph in question, they will be as efficient as you can be.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you're not going to do any better than some kind of search (as you alluded to). I wouldn't worry too much about efficiency: these algorithms are generally linear in the number of nodes + edges.

The problem is a bit underspecified, so I'll make some assumptions about your data structure:

1. You know vertex u (because you didn't ask to find it)
2. You can iterate both the inbound and outbound edges of a node (efficiently)
3. You can iterate all nodes in the graph
4. You can (efficiently) associate a couple bits of data along with each node

In this case, use a convenient search starting from vertex u (depth/breadth, doesn't matter) twice: once following the outbound edges (marking nodes as "reachable from u") and once following the inbound edges (marking nodes as "reaching u"). Finally, iterate through all nodes and compare the two bits according to your purpose.

Note: as worded, your result set includes all nodes that do not reach vertex u. If you intended the conjunction instead of the implication, then you can save a little time by incorporating the test in the second search, rather than scanning all nodes in the graph. This also relieves assumption 3.